# How do I store two rows of serial data with ser.readline in Python?

Tags: python, serial-port

I'm receiving a line in serial port with the format 'number1 number2'

now I'd like to save each row in their respective array, just the 50 first values for each

the code i'm using is:

```
import serial
from array import*

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)

volt=array('L',[])
curr=array('L',[])
x=int(0)

while x<50:

      line = ser.readline()
      data = [int(val) for val in line.split()]
      print data
      volt.append(data[0])
      curr.append(data[1])
      x=x+1

print volt
print curr
```

The list 'data' is saved correctly: [number 1, number2]
Also, there is no problem with data[0]

But, when I try to access data[1], it says list index is out of range

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated, and sorry for my bad English

Comment: What is the exact entire error message? copy-paste it into your question, please.

Comment: Also, can you reproduce the problem using `ser = sys.stdin` instead of the `Serial` object you are using now?

Comment: [4373]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "save_serial.py", line 16, in <module>
    curr.append(data[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I found, sometimes it just reads one line.. sometimes the two lines and works perfect. Is there a problem with the serial read?

Comment: well, I found how to fix it.. forcing the program to store only if length of 'data' is 2. thanks for your interest

Comment: I don't know if there is a problem with `ser.readline()`. You could test that theory with `print line, repr(line)` immediately after the call to `ser.readline()`.